# Google OAuth 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm just looking at the document for google [OAuth 2](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer.html)

Why do the example links provided repeatedly show the consent page even after consenting the demos access to my account information?

My understanding is that once consent is given you should no longer be prompted? What am I misunderstanding? I am having the same issue in an asp.net MVC application I am building.

Comment: I agree, I don't think it should repeatedly prompt. A name-value pair that can be added to the query string, &approval_prompt=force, to force the user to consent every time the application requests a token, but this isn't on the example urls. If this parameter is not passed (as per the examples), then you shouldn't be prompted after the initial consent, for the same client_id and scope.

Comment: David, Can you share your MVC code for OAuth 2?  I'm having problems authenticating with ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Either the OAuth2 token set to expire too quickly which causes you to re-authorize, or you are not reusing the token with each request and you have to get a new token each time, which is causing you to authorize for the first time, over and over.

Hope this helps!